# Wrap multiple asmx webservices in one file

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-3.5

For a new website we're creating an API/Webservice which will serve the data to the frontend. Because of the size the database behind the website (100+ tables all requiring a select/update/delete method) it will get pretty messy if you put all methods in one page. The idea is to create a single .asmx webservice file for each table/function making things a lot more maintainable. But this method requires every webservice to be referenced individually in the frontend. Is it possible to wrap all the seperate webservices in one wrapper and target the individual webservices using a variable in the URL (e.g. ?targetWS=XX)

We're running C#, .Net 3.5

Thanks

Comment: .ASMX (legacy web services) are at best deprecated in .NET. You're on 3.5 - you should be doing this in WCF.

Comment: Is the only difference the tables and related stored procedures/queries?

Comment: You might also look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx)